# How to Sign ssl on server

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto broker server. I have enabled ssl as instructed here: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/

But this is self signed certificate. I have only read about adding ssl to websites. How do I add ssl to a mosquitto server so that it can be accessed from sites on https.

Should I buy a certificate from a CA and then follow the steps given in the link?

I don't know how I would add ssl to a server

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here. Do you want to use MQTT over Websockets (this is the only way to use it with a web browser)? or Just native MQTT. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59412971/edit) the question to add a LOT more detail.

Comment: @hardillb I'm using mqtt over websockets. I have self signed the certificate now. Do I have to get a certificate from a CA to be able to  access the broker from a https website?

Comment: As I asked, please in future edit the question to add details. Also please read the doc on what a good question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @hardillb a self signed certificate won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want your site to be used be anybody and not just browsers you have direct control over (where you could add your own CA to the trusted list).

You will need to obtain a certificate signed by a trusted CA (this could be a purchased one or from a provider like LetsEncrypt) so the browser will allow the connection to complete.

The browsers will not prompt a user to accept a untrusted (e.g. self signed) certificate for a websocket connection as it does for loading a webpage.

Once you have a trusted certificate then you will need to follow the instructions specific to the broker you are using to configure it to use the certificate.

Comment: Can I host a mosquitto broker on vm machine on azure and access it from a website?

Comment: That is a totally separate question, but what makes you think you wouldn't be able to?

Comment: I have hosted it on a machine. But I don't know how to make the broker accessible over the Internet

Comment: Please give me an idea as to how I can make the broker accessible over the Internet. I'll try to figure out the rest on my own

Comment: If I just run it on a vm will I be able to access it from a different network?