# How to install ssl for mosquitto

Tags: javascript, ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I have followed the instructions here: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/  to enable ssl.

It is a self signed certificate and when I try to access the broker over the internet from a web page, I get `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`.

When  I type the websocket address as `https://websocketaddress/`, I get the warning and when I click proceed and then reload the page accessing the websocket address, I am able to access the broker and get values.

So it is because it's a self signed certificate, I get that error.

My question is what is the procedure to add ssl after I buy the certificate from a  CA?

Comment: You should ignore step 1 to 7 if you intend to buy a certificate from a CA... . Just start from step 8

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee i dont understand what he means by copy to client. I can't add it to every client that access the broker over the internet?

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee i also need the step3 and step4 to send to the CA, right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is because you are using a self signed certificate.

If you are using a self signed certificate then you have to manually distribute the CA cert to EVERY client that wants to use the broker.

As I said in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59421698/504554) to your last question about this, if you want it to be accessible to everybody on the internet then you will need to use a certificate from a trusted public CA. The CA cert from these sources are already included in the browser so you don't need to add them.

You can either pay a CA for a certificate that will most likely come with a years life, or you can use LetsEncrypt who will supply a free certificate with a 90 day life, but they also supply a tool that can renew the certificate for you and you can script it to update the certificate then restart mosquitto.

The procedure for setting up mosquitto will be the same, you just need use the files from the CA.

For a paid for Certificate, you will generate a private key, then from that create a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) which you send to the CA and they will send back a certificate.

For LetsEncrypt, the command line tool will handle creating a private key and CSR for you and sending it to the CA to get a certificate. The files will be stored in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/[hostname]/`. Make sure you use the `fullchain.pem` for the CA cert entry in mosquitto.conf.